# How does getBlock('meta') work in DocPad?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docpad, static-site

I'm moving a website from a different site generator to [DocPad](http://www.docbad.org) and am trying to understand the *getBlock('meta')* feature. Figuring out *getBlock('scripts')* and *getBlock('styles')* was pretty easy since I only needed to pass individual resource locations to the *.add* method in an array with each location taking up a single space. Generating meta tags on the other hand seems like it has to be slightly more complicated since there are two components to each tag: a name and a value.

My question is, how do I pass meta tag names and values to *getBlock('meta').add()* in order for it to create some meta tags for me?

Also, I've noticed *getBlock('meta')* creates a tag by default:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Powered-By" content="DocPad"/>
```

I prefer not to have in my markup. I am all for attributing the awesome DocPad project, however I prefer to do it in a different way and in a different location. How can I prevent that tag from being generated?

Thank you.

Comment: In the bootstrap skeleton, i found this line:
<code><!-- Output DocPad produced meta elements -->
<%- @getBlock('meta').toHTML() %>
</code>
Seems like inserting that line just adds the DocPad specific meta tags...

Answer (score 2):

@przemo_li and @Rafael Epplee are right, by a standard installation the meta block will only output that, if you have the time to submit a pull request to make that powered-by meta element optional via  a docpad configuration option - I'd happily accept it.

However, the point of it isn't just to output that powered-by element, but to enable plugins to inject their own meta data - I'm not aware of any plugins that do so yet, but a great example could be given from @Rafael's example - where you define meta element via your document's meta data, then use a plugin to inject them into the meta block, allowing you to have page specific meta data easily. Another example is perhaps injecting the charset/encoding meta element appropriately depending on the document's encoding, rather than the layout always using the standard utf8 encoding.

So while it isn't that useful now, one day a plugin may need it.

Comment: Could you please link to this example by @Rafael? I can't seem to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just forget about it.

Hand write your own meta. In your layout.

As long as you do not need page specific meta you are good to go.

And if you need it than you can always change source code of DocPad.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that docpad does nothing with arguments given to `getBlock('meta').add()`. I had a look at the source and the other blocks all generate some block-specific HTML on add() while the meta block doesn't.

My guess is that docpad automagically collects Metadata from the documents and inserts them into the meta block in some other way.

I think at the moment the only possible way to add meta data to your site is using either the documents or the docpad.coffee file.

Comment: "It seems to me that docpad does nothing with arguments given to getBlock('meta').add(). I had a look at the source and the other blocks all generate some block-specific HTML on add() while the meta block doesn't." seems like a bug, should definitely work. Can you file an issue with more details on the github issue tracker and post the link? Cheers.

Comment: At the Moment I don't even know how it should work :P You mean the expected behaviour would be that the arguments given to `add()` are injected to the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is quite late, but as of now Docpad is v6.78.4 and provides means of hooking to events, which is what we need.

First, Docpad *meta* is a surprisingly uneventful [MetaCollection](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/blob/master/src/lib/collections/meta.coffee), which is basically an array of items with a `.toHTML()` method to join them into a string. It is called a *block* because it resides in a different structure that can be modified elsewhere, and has a set of separate methods, such as `getBlock()` and `setBlock()`

[Events](http://docpad.org/docs/events) are predefined points, at which user code can be triggered. I suggest using generateBefore for the meta thing, so that it is set before any content is produced:

```
# Define the DocPad Configuration
docpadConfig = {
    # ...
    events:
        generateBefore: () ->
            @docpad.getBlock('meta').add('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>')
}
```

As for the second concern, meta `generator` (I guess it was X-Powered-By in the question) is added conditionally in `DocPad.prototype.resetCollections`:

```
if (docpad.getConfig().poweredByDocPad !== false) {
    meta.add("<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"DocPad v" + (docpad.getVersion()) + "\" />");
}
```

You can disable it by adding a `poweredByDocPad: false` in your `docpad.coffee` file.